What is the difference between 'Flow Control Action' and timer
What is the difference between 'Flow Control Action' and timer? In Flow Control Action we give think time (Delay between actions) and timers also we give delay between samples. Kindly give me real-life example to make a difference both of them.
I just want to know the differences in Flow Control Action and Timers

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.


JMeter Timers are executed before every Sampler in their scope. Also there are "smarter" timers allowing setting the number of requests per minute/second/hour without calculating the pacing time
Flow Control Action Sampler is executed exactly where it's placed. If can also be used for controlling the logical "flow" like exit the current loop, start new iteration of the current loop, stop thread or the whole test

